# how do i convert all materials in a loaded gltf from mesh basic to mesh phong?

Tags: three.js, 3d, gltf

I am loading a GLTF model into threejs. All the materials used on the object (and there a quite a few of them), use a mesh basic material, and we want them to be a material that can be affected by lights. Is there a way to convert all materials from a basic material to one that can receive lights, like Phong (including their existing properties?).

I can currently add a new material as follows:

```
glb.scene.traverse(child => {
        if (child.isMesh) {
          //child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ flatShading: true });
        }
      });
```

but everything just looks a solid gray color and doesn't contain any of the properties of the mesh basic material it replaced.

Comment: You gatta copy the textures and properties from the original material

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default material in glTF is usually mapped to MeshStandardMaterial in three.js — your model must have the "unlit" glTF extension (`KHR_materials_unlit`) enabled if it's creating MeshBasicMaterial. Short of changing that in a modeling tool like Blender, which might be easiest, you can also convert it in three.js...

```js
model.traverse((child) => {

  if ( ! child.isMesh ) return;

  var prevMaterial = child.material;

  child.material = new MeshPhongMaterial();

  MeshBasicMaterial.prototype.copy.call( child.material, prevMaterial );

});
```

Note that the reverse does not necessarily work — calling a complex material's `copy()` method on a simpler material (like MeshBasicMaterial) will cause it to look for properties that do not exist.

Comment: IIRC this is not enough, `child.material` can be an array of materials?

Comment: In three.js broadly, yes. But when loading glTF, THREE.GLTFLoader will never create multi-material meshes (except in some older three.js versions).

Comment: I guess I ran into those older versions because I had to add the check for "is array" and because the docs say in general that the material property can be an array.

Comment: Yeah, removed in r103 with https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15889.